# Why am I getting an incorrect date from the timestamp I send through?

Tags: php, date

Here is my code and the date that should be returned is **2014-08-22 04:21:24** but for some reason I'm getting **1967-11-06 12:08:32** when passing in the timestamp of **1408681284000**

```
    $test = convertDate();
    echo $test;
    function convertDate() {
        $test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1408681284000);
        return $test;
    }
```

If anybody knows why this is happening then I would appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I get `46609-05-02 07:40:00`

Comment: FYI, `date` accepts a timestamp in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Do you need it in milliseconds?

Comment: Ah ok thanks. No I don't need it in milliseconds but something like this would work right?                                       `$seconds = 1408681284000 / 1000;
 $test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $seconds);
 return $test;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds, but PHP expects them to be seconds.

Divide the timestamp by 1000 and you'll get the time you expect:

```
$test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1408681284);
```

I get `2014-08-22 00:21:24`, but I'm in a different timezone from you.

Comment: `date` uses whatever the default timezone is. So his result just means his timezone is UTC, which is different from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your time is in milliseconds you should change it to seconds.

If you don't want to use seconds you can use:

`strtotime()` with `date()` into whatever format you want.

```
$mydate = "2014-08-22";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($myDate));
```